# General equation of sphere through a plane and a circle

Tags: 3d

Given the equation of circle $x^{2} + y^{2} = a^{2}$
and the equation of the plane $z=0$

Why is the general equation of sphere through them written as 
$x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} - a^{2} + \lambda(z) = 0$

From where does the term $z^{2}$ comes in the picture ?

However in other cases, if equation of circle is $C$ and plane be $P$, we write sphere's equation as $ C + \lambda(P) = 0$

Comment: What do you mean by sphere through a plane and circle?

Comment: Sphere such that its intersection with the given plane is given circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where hace you got last equation from, but the general fórmula of an sphere is $(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+(z-z_0)^2=a^2$. So if you don't hace the $z^2$ term, you wouldn't have an sphere, if $\lambda(P)$ is not equal to that value.